# Does Spring Model have capacity upper bound?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new with Spring MVC framework. And I just learnt that data can be transferred between Controller and View by means of Model's attributes. But how much data can Model hold during transmission? Does it have a capacity upper bound?

Comment: It's just an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the model in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175932/what-exactly-is-the-model-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no capacity or limit imposed by `Spring` on the model size. Think of `Model` as just a java object. The Controller simply transfers data between model and view. So if your model has 1000 attributes that map to some view elements, Spring won't complain. But just think if it is even practical to have that many dynamic elements in a view. You might say that you might be fetching 1000 rows from the database and want to display them in the view. But those 1000 rows can be grouped as a `List` object - only one attribute.

Secondly, most servers (not Spring) impose a size restriction on `get` request and return 414 if the request is too long (say, because of too many criteria or request parameters which are model attributes for Spring). In such cases, you will have to restrict yourself to using `post`.

Long story short, rather than discovering whether Spring imposes a size limit on the model (which it does not), you should investigate in why you have too many model attributes at first. There is most likely something wrong in your design.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :) !