# Why is the point of function in laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel

Why do I need to define function in laravel Model folder for a file. Say I have a model Module.php now when Module extends model values are read from module table. Why do I need a function to operate on database when I can use a function in controller?

here is Module.php:

```
public function getStudentModules($id) {

    $student = Students::where('user_id', $id)->get();

    \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $modules = \DB::table('course_modules')->
    where('course_id', '=', $student[0]->course_id)->
    select('module_id')->
    get();

    \DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

    $results = Module::join('users', 'modules.lecturer_id', '=', 'users.id')->
    select('users.email', 'modules.id', 'modules.lecturer_id', 'modules.name', 'modules.code')->
    where('modules.semester', '=', $student[0]->semester)->
    whereIn('modules.id', $modules)->get();

    return $results;
}
```

Here is controller:

```
public function lecturerViewExaminations($id)
  {
    $examinations =  /*Module::join('examination', 'modules.id', '=', 'examination.module_id')->
    select('modules.name as modulename', 'modules.code as modulecode', 'examination.name', 'examination.startdate', 'examination.enddate', 'examination.duration', 'examination.type', 'examination.code', 'examination.status', 'examination.id')->
    where('modules.lecturer_id', '=', $id)->get();*/

    return json_encode($examinations);
  }
```

Why the  definition in Module.php when I can enter that function i n a controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the model in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175932/what-exactly-is-the-model-in-mvc) and [many, many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+what+is+the+purpose+of+model+in+mvc)

Comment: no not duplicate

Comment: Because, the Model should contain buisness logic and it should "Model" your data.  The controller is the Glue that ties the Model to the View.  The View is the response message ( output ) of your app

Comment: If you want the "reason" for that I has to do with many principals of good programming,  DRY ( don't repeat yourself ), Separation of Concerns, Responsibility .. etc.

Comment: It is a duplicate because you clearly don't understand what a model is and why it's there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm feeling nice, so I will give you my thoughts on the why.

A lot of it has to do with DRY, Don't repeat yourself. Generally in MVC architecture you cant really access a Controller from say another controller.  Basically you don't load or instantiate the controllers.  The architecture does that.  So by putting the DB code in the Controller you may not be able to easily access it from outside the controller. This would cause you to have to duplicate some code in many places in the controller, where if you use a model, you can easily access and reuse it.  Then when you make a schema update, you will have to search though all your bloated controller methods and change stuff.

Separation of concerns, the Controller shouldn't be concerned with the business logic of your data. For example, say you have a profile page.  Now the controller shouldn't be concerned with how Users Model interacts with the database.  It already has to worry about giving the data to the User model, picking what view to use, and assigning any output to the view.  To make it responsible for the fine grained interactions with the Database, puts to much responsibility in the hands of the controller.  What happens is instead of a method that is a few hundred lines of code, you could wind up with one that is a few thousand. At that point you might as well just procedural program it. Again this makes it hard to maintain your code because it can be hard to tell what a given controller is responsible for.  Whereas a User model, should be fairly obvious what it's responsible for.  You wouldn't expect the User Model to deal with say, products, or the credit card processing.  It's too much responsibility.  You wouldn't ask a police officer, to do surgery on you.  And you wouldn't ask the surgeon to arrest the guy you got beat up by at the bar.

Black box, Models should be basically a black box.  The controllers or views should not be concerned with the inner workings of them.  They shouldn't care what DB driver is used ( MySLQ, MSSQL, SqlLite etc ). Nor, What table they use, or if it uses files or what path those files are at etc.  They shouldn't know and shouldn't care, as they have their own job to worry about. The controllers interact only with the "interface" the models provide.  This way you could replace the guts of a Model as long as it maintains the same interface you ideally wouldn't need to make any code changes to the Controller.

I am sure there are others but these are the big ones I can think of that relate to your question.

If you start mixing everything up you will eventually wind up with spaghetti code.  In a fast paced production environment, it's hard enough to keep it organized while implementing all these idea, trust me.

I'm actually not a Huge fan of MVC, it tends to be a bit too rigid for my liking.   Some of that depends on the MVC framework though.  What I mean is a lot of them wind up based off of some strong naming conventions, and locations requirements. For example all the controllers have to be in a folder named Controllers, all the  Models have to be in a folder named Models.   It makes it harder to make stand alone "plugins" because your constrained by either their naming conventions or structure.  You wind up with a lot of code that is strongly bound to the framework.

That's my 2 cents.

PS.  I am actually building an Event Driven MVC framework :)